# Sinon usefaketimer an the spy called count miss

Tags: unit-testing, sinon

this is my code. I want to test the "doing" method and verify the `this.obj.send` called count with time interval.

My problem is when I stub the method of `_fetchAllDatas` and resolve. the `this.obj.send` could not called. and when the `this.obj.send` move to `_fetchAllDatas` outside. it can be called.

How can I deal with this problem ?? thanks ~

```
var sinon = require('sinon');


class A {
    constructor(obj){
        this.obj = obj;
        this.timer;
    }

    doing(){
        this.timer = setInterval(()=>{
            this._fetchAllDatas().then((data)=>{
                console.log('!!!',data);
                this.obj.send(data);
            });
        },1000)
    }

    stop(){
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    }

    _fetchAllDatas(){
        return Promise.resolve([]);
    }
}

var sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create();
var spy = { send: sandbox.spy()};
var a = new A(spy);
var stub = sandbox.stub(a,'_fetchAllDatas').resolves(['mark']);
var clock = sandbox.useFakeTimers();

a.doing();;
clock.tick(5000);
 sinon.assert.callCount(spy.send, 5); // error the count is zero. it should be 5 times
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the result of `"call count = 5 times within 5 seconds"` will not happen as expected.
It's simply because the callback of the `setInterval` will be trigger after N(ms) of delay time;
That is, it will only happen four times within 5s duration, like the graph below:

```
x = not triggered
o = triggered

1s--1s--1s--1s--1s
x   o   o   o   o
^start          ^end
```

Second, you will not get the right result from an async call right after a sync call.
When you calling `a.doing();`, it initiates a synchronize version of `setInterval` (Because of `useFakeTimers`)
that will calls a function `this._fetchAllDatas()`
that returns a Promise which runs an asynchronize callback,
which means `this.obj.send(data)` will be executed asynchronously.

Even if you use `clock.tick(5000)`, it's still an asynchronize call.

That is, you should put your assertion at the right time after the Promise is truly resolved.